# A convoluted/modified Haversine algorithm issue

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, distance, google-places-api, haversine

Using the Haversine's algorithm and using the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839604/haversine-formula-php-mysql) I found half of my solution. So here is the problem:

User A who is standing at "Nazareth" and having a 50km radar around it, I am able to find all the other users in that range using the algorithm linked above. Now my problem is, the user standing at Point B (user near Newark) who also has a radar of 50km, intersects with the radar of User A.

So along with the results which I was able to fetch which falls under user A's radar of 50km, using the above algorithm, I also want to include all the users (like user B) whose radars intersect.

I am not sure if this is the right algorithm to be used or should I have a completely different approach towards this query of mine.

[image: Google maps and Google places integration]

Following is the query I have written to just fetch the all the users who fall under user A's radar of 50km and I am getting the most accurate results which was the first part of the problem.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    users     
WHERE 
    acos(sin(".$user_location_A['latitude'].") * sin(radians(latitude)) + 
cos(".$user_location_A['latitude'].") * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - 
(".$user_location_A['longitude']."))) * 6371 <= 50
```

The explanation for the above query is as follows:

1. sin(radians(`latitude`)), cos(radians(`latitude`)) -- The latitude here is the column name latitude in the users table for each user
2. cos(radians(`longitude`) -- The longitude here is the column name longitude in the users table for each user
3. `50` at the end of the query is the 50km radius that I want to create a radar of.

Comment: Not sure what you want.All of A & B (removing Duplicates) Only those both in A & B ?

Comment: Do all the radars have the same radius?

Comment: Answer to comment-1:
1. I need all users who are in within A's radar (which I am already getting)
2. I also need users whose radar intersect with that of A, like user B

Answer to comment-2:
No, not necessarily, the radars of each user can be different, is that a problem ?

Answer (score 1):

If all the radars have a 50 km radius, then any radar whose center is within 100 km  of A will intersect with it.  If they have different radii, then the distance of interest is 50 km (radius of A) + R km (where R is the radius of B's radar).